# Best computer for mining Monero

Tags: monerod, mining, cpu-mining

Hi I am a newbie in Mining.

My question is: which one is the best computer for mining Monero?
I know about the electricity costs (for me are extremely low) and I am not interested in become a new crypto millionaire. I only want to mine Monero using the best possible hardware in a range of 2000$. :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Ryzen 3000 series CPUs are considered the most cost effective.